# XSS on Web site URL of Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, xss

**Edit**: Fixed!

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/smark
```

Comment: I fear the day users create accounts to launch attacks on unsuspecting recruiters, I thought plain old resumes were good enough ... then some NLP at the interview.

Comment: Ohhhh boy! Finally an opportunity to test `$("div").wrap("<marquee>");` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed, thanks for reporting it.  The Website URL field wasn't being HTML encoded, and the regex that was making sure it looked like a valid URL was missing a `$` on the end, so it was really only making sure it *started* with a valid URL.  Both bugs have been fixed.